# AngularJS $stateful filter with $timeout stuck looping

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-filters

I'm trying to create a stateful filter with AngularJS to eventually call a service that will return data asynchronously. To test this, I'm just using a simple $timeout function that console.logs a string. However, this console.log is just running infinitely.

```
export default angular.module('components.filters.combine-name', [])

.filter('combineName', ['$timeout', function ($timeout) {
  function combineName(input) {
    $timeout(function () {
      console.log('test');
    }, 1000);
    return input.firstName + ' ' + input.lastName;
  }

  combineName.$stateful = true;
  return combineName;
}]);
```

html

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-responsive">
    <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <div class="th">
          Name
        </div>
      </th>
      <th>
        <div class="th">
          Status
        </div>
      </th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="result in vm.results">
      <td>{{result | combineName}}</td>
      <td>{{result.status}}</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

controller:

```
this.results = [
  {
    firstName: 'Johnny',
    lastName: 'Utah',
    status: 'Active'
  },
  {
    firstName: 'Richard',
    lastName: 'Reynolds',
    status: 'Inactive'
  },
  {
    firstName: 'Randy',
    lastName: 'Johnson',
    status: 'Active'
  }
];
```

Comment: $timeout triggers digest, filter runs each digest... thats infinite loop

Answer (score 0):

With $timeout, you basically turn on the looping and it will keep doing so, unless you tell it to stop.

Inside your loop use: $timeout.cancel();